# How to convert @bottle.route to bottle.route() when serving static files?

Tags: python, bottle

I usually use the [method version](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.route) to handle routing in bottle

```
bottle.route("/charge", "GET", self.charge)
```

The bottle docs heavily rely on the `@route` decorator to handle the routing and I have one case I do not know how to convert into my favorite version. The docs on [serving static files](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#static-files) use the example

```
from bottle import static_file

@route('/static/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/path/to/static/files')
```

Is there a way to turn that into some kind of

```
bottle.route("/static", "GET", static_file)
```

construction? In particular I am confused by how to pass the `filename` and `root` parameters to `static_file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer doesn't solve your problem nicely, so I'll chime in.  You seem to be trying to use Bottle's `static_file` as a route target, but it's not meant to be used that way.  As the example you cited demonstrates, `static_file` is meant to be called from *within* a route target function.  Here's a complete working example:

```
import bottle

class AAA(object):
    def __init__(self, static_file_root):
        self.static_file_root = static_file_root

    def assign_routes(self):
        bottle.route('/aaa', 'GET', self.aaa)
        bottle.route('/static/<filename:path>', 'GET', self.send_static)

    def aaa(self):
        return ['this is aaa\n']

    def send_static(self, filename):
        return bottle.static_file(filename, self.static_file_root)

aaa = AAA('/tmp')
aaa.assign_routes()
bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Example usage:

```
% echo "this is foo" > /tmp/foo
% curl http://localhost:8080/static/foo
this is foo
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this that simple? :) I would have sworn I tried it several times. Thanks a lot (switching accepted answer and +1)

Answer (score 1):

since you want to use single method, you must pass the parameters to the `static_file` by yourself, and use `re` to parse them at first.

the code will looks like this:

```
from bottle import Router

app.route('/static/:filename#.*#', "GET", static_file(list(Router()._itertokens('/static/:filename#.*#'))[1][2], root='./static/'))
```

this is a little long and if you want to parse the parameter outside, than you may add another parse function.

I know you want to make all your routers looks clean and in good order, but the decorator is to rich the function but keep the function itself clean, for AOP, so why not try to use decorators in this situation.

Comment: Thank you. It is not that I do not like the decorator version, but I cannot use it on methods in a class. `bottle.route("/aaa", "GET", self.aaa)` works while `@bottle.route("/aaa")` which decorates `def aaa(self)` does not (`TypeError: aaa() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`)